# android button is over listview

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout

first, I want to say sorry but i have my problems with designing android app :D 
I want that the button is below the listview. Actually the button is over the listview and hide the lower region. How can I fix it?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzUze.png)

My layout file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="de.app.me.de.MyFragment">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/listview_ticket"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"

                />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_reply"
        android:text="Antworten"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You should use LinearLayout with orientation  set to vertical instead of FrameLayout. Reason : Views added last are on top of the stack. Since button is added last it will always we on top on list view. Hope I was clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context="de.app.me.de.MyFragment">
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_reply"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview_ticket"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"

        />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/btn_reply"
    android:text="Antworten"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
```

basically, just change FrameLayout to RelativeLayout and align button at bottom and make listview above buttons by adding layout_above to swipeRefreshLayout

Comment: it does not solve the error. Maby my java code help: http://pastebin.com/B4U6y8nj

Comment: your id are mismatch please match correct id and clean the project to resolve the issue

Comment: i alredy updatet the id in the layout and java code.

Comment: then please continue in chat and send me the updated xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102158/discussion-between-eiskaltereistee-and-ankitagrawal).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `FrameLayout`:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

And remove from your `ListView`:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

**EDIT**

Try this with your button:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:id="@+id/btn_reply"
android:text="Antworten"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:background="@color/orange"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Now, the same problem but not at the buttom, its on the top ^^ :) http://pastebin.com/wPZ5migz

Answer (score 0):

You can change the parent class to RelativeLayout. and in the ListView set the following attribute

```
android:layout_above="@+id/button"
```

and for the button set the following attribute

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

RelativeLayout is meant for these kinds of rendering.